# how to install python-opencv on mac os 10.11

Tags: python, opencv

I have been try to install opencv by brew

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install opencv
cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py cv.py
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so cv2.so
```

after i run `python -c "import cv2;  print cv2.__version__"`

i got

> ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so,
>   2): Library not loaded: lib/libopencv_shape.3.0.dylib   Referenced
>   from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so   Reason: unsafe
>   use of relative rpath lib/libopencv_shape.3.0.dylib in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so with restricted binary

i have been try to download opencv source (opencv 3.0) code to install ,it still not work same error for me. anyone can tell me why ?

when i set python path on ~/.bash_profile i got 
[image: IDE can detect cv2]

IDE can detact cv2.os but i still got error

> ImportError: No module named cv2

Answer (score 2):

You can install opencv using pip(probably pip3 if you are on a mac).

Just type :

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

If you want a specific version

Do :

```
pip3 install opencv-python==*version*
```

Then import it wherever you want to use it.

```
import cv2
```

Comment: Also works on python 2.7, using just pip of course.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises due to the fact that `cv2.so` from python site-packages tries to link to a file which can not be found. The reason for it not to be found is because brew installs the file in different locations. Here are the set of steps to resolve this.

1. Find if your cv2.so links anywhere

   `ls -l /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

   Among other things, it should show a

   `3056 -rwxr-xr-x    1 admin  1563612 Oct 23 00:33 cv2.so`

   If this is the case, your `cv2.so` needs to be linked.
2. Check your python packages for opencv from brew directory.

   `ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so`

   If this file exists, it is the file that needs to be linked. If this file does not exist then (a) Your versions may be different, so change that accordingly. (b) Your opencv installation may have issues. Try uninstalling and reinstalling opencv again
3. Link the file from brew directory

   `ln -s -f /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so`

This should correctly link your `cv2.so` file thus resulting in removing this error.

Comment: after import, i am getting "ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cv2)"

I linked the cv2.so file and also included the Lib folder in the PATH as well

Answer (score 0):

First, create a `venv` (Virtual Enviorment)

```
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

Then using brew :

```
brew uninstall opencv
brew install opencv3
```

**OR**

Then using pip :

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Finally, import using :

```
import cv2
```

This should work but in the case doesn't it might mean that you've installed anaconda with python in that case try:

```
conda install -c menpo opencv
```

Finally, import using :

```
import cv2
```