# Python-opencv Error import cv2 ImportError: dlopen after update of OS X El Capitan

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I have this error when import cv2 after update the system of OS X El Capitan

```
import cv2

ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded: lib/libopencv_shape.3.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
  Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath lib/libopencv_shape.3.0.dylib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so with restricted binary
```

I have tried the method in [Cannot import cv2 because unsafe use of relative rpath lib in cv2.so with restricted binary](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5447)

```
rebuild build use  cmake -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: A systematic way to resolve this is described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33514309/229341

Answer (score 2):

This is because of SIP (System Integrity Protection) introduced in El Capitan [link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899).

I too faced the same issue and came across this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343299/mysql-improperly-configured-reason-unsafe-use-of-relative-path). Basically, the relative path dependencies listed in the shared libs need to be changed to absolute paths. There are huge number of these to be corrected in opencv libraries. You can optionally disable SIP. I preferred to change the links instead and wrote the following python snippet.

Change the ABSPATH and LIBPATHS if required. It can be used for any other libraries as well. It will create rPathChangeCmd.txt which you can paste in the terminal. It will also create rPathChangeErr.txt in case of any errors. I would suggest check error file (if created) before pasting the commands.

```
import glob
import subprocess
import os.path

ABSPATH = "/usr/local/lib/"  # absolute path to relative libraries
# libraries to correct
LIBPATHS = ['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so', '/usr/local/lib/libopencv*'] 

PREFIX = 'sudo install_name_tool -change '

assert(ABSPATH.startswith('/') and ABSPATH.endswith('/'), 
    'please provide absolute library path ending with /')

libs = []
for path in LIBPATHS:
  libs += glob.glob(path)

cmd =  []
err = []
for lib in libs:
  if not os.path.isfile(lib):
    err.append(lib+" library not found") # glob should take care
  datastr = subprocess.check_output(['otool','-l','-v', lib])
  data = datastr.split('\n') 
  for line in data:
    ll = line.split()
    if not ll: continue
    if (ll[0] == 'name' and ll[1].endswith('.dylib') and not ll[1].startswith('/')):
      libname = ll[1].split('/')[-1]
      if os.path.isfile(ABSPATH+libname):  
        cmd.append(PREFIX+ll[1]+" "+ABSPATH+libname+' '+lib)
      else:
        err.append(ABSPATH+libname+" does not exist, hence can't correct: "+ll[1]+" in: "+lib)

ohandle = open("rpathChangeCmd.txt", 'w')
for lib in cmd:
  ohandle.write(lib+'\n')
ohandle.close()

if err:
  ehandle = open("rpathChangeErr.txt", 'w')
  for e in err:
    ehandle.write(e+'\n')
  ehandle.close()
```